# RecyclerView Hiding LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView and LinearLayout in one of my Quote Application like below.

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >


    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/pageNavLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/butPrev"
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_white_24dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <View
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPageCount"
            android:clickable="true"
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Page 1 0f 67"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/butNext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/pageNavLayout"
        android:id="@+id/listQuoteView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when I press next button and RecyclerView List another Quote...its hiding MY LinearLayout for some time and when I scroll it, its showing it. I have used LinearLayout for my bottom bar. What I am missing and What I should do for show always bottom bar ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code that you're using? The XML doesn't tell us much, such as whether or not your hiding elements or resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"` in your `RecyclerView` to make it visible all the time as your `LinearLayout` height is `40dp` (As per your code).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
       android:id="@+id/listQuoteView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:weight="1"
       android:layout_height="0dp">
     </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/pageNavLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:weight="1"
  android:layout_height="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/butPrev"
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_white_24dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <View
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPageCount"
            android:clickable="true"
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Page 1 0f 67"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/butNext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of an element that's *fixed* to the bottom of the screen:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#26ffffff"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/today_last_sync"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

You need to make sure that you are using the following setting on the child XML:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

As well as the parent container having:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```